# Integrating a vue.js project into existing html-based code

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, npm, deployment

im a beginner when it comes to vue.js and inexperienced in web-development in general.

I've been tasked with remaking a a part of a page on a website of one of our clients.

One of the most important requirements for me was that the project should be easy to integrate into existing code and should be able to accept various arguments (like props in vue.js do)

I've finished the project but I'm currently quite lost on how I should proceed with creating a deployable component. I originally thought that it would be really easy to turn my project into a standalone component that would then take some arguments via props like this.                               .

However after searching on the internet it doesn't appear that straightforward anymore.

The best option I came up with so far is uploading my project to npm to make it easily installable and then provide some instructions on how to integrate it into code. However, that process could vary heavily depending on which type of html and js the client uses.

Another option would be hosting the component on github pages and then providing an iframe to it, however it seems like that would make passing down arguments to the component require a separate api.

Is there something really obvious that I'm missing here? What options do I have to create a reusable component that can be just inserted into existing code, regadless of the framework?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

I've tried looking up similar questions but the answers seem to be rather obscure and utilize some odd packages via cdns

Comment: It's unclear why you want to deliver the part of the page through third parties (npm, github pages) and not deploy it on client's website directly. That's an awkward way to do this, not to mention that you'll make it available for everyone this way. You don't need an iframe, bundled vue app is js+css files that can be loaded as any other

Comment: Well as of right now, I don't actually have the access to the their website but I figured I  could publish a scoped/private npm package and then send them the access details so they could integrate it. When you talk about "bundled" vue app, Im assuming you are referring the files produced upon building the project? Thank you for your response btw, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, I mean build artifacts (dist folder). You don't need private npm for such tasks, private git repo will do the trick. Npm project can be easily installable remotely when done right but you can add "dist" to the repo to guarantee this, not the best way to do this but will serve the purpose. This is very specific to project setup, which is unknown. Common Vue setups (Vue CLI and Vite) are configured for SPA, the output are html+js+css assets in dist. html is there to load css+js and provide root element, which have unique names for each build to prevent unwanted caching

Comment: And root element is something like <div id="root">. You need to config the setup to use the selector you need and stop generating unique asset names, so it could be loaded from another page with code like <div id=myapp><script src="/myapp/myapp.js"><script src="/myapp/myapp.anotherchunk.js">, where myapp/ is dist/ folder that's deployed to a server. After you got rid of unique names, you can copy and paste the code for embed from dist/index.html. The problem with caching that they were supposed to avoid will still remain

Comment: Thanks for your response, so what you are basically saying is that ./dist directory can be dragged into the existing project where the vue components can be simply referenced by their 'id' declared in the main.js file? Thanks in advance

Comment: Not specifically components, it's init code that's responsible for this. The regular main.js for Vue app is `app.mount('#myapp')`, it will work correctly for embed code above

Comment: Hey, I've tried out this approach but I ran into two issues. First of all creating or importing the components from inside of the .js file like this: <script type="module">
        import { createApp } from 'vue'
        import MyComponent from '././my-component.js'

        createApp(MyComponent).mount('#app')
    </script> requires the imported components to be .js files and not .vue, which means I would have to rewrite my whole project. Second of all, it doesn't seem to work with the built files either despite them being in compiled to .js as well.

Comment: "requires the imported components to be .js files and not .vue," - this isn't what I suggested above. /myapp/myapp.js is supposed to be bundled script. What exactly didn't work with built files? If there are errors they need to be addressed

Comment: So what I've been doing so far was trying to load the existing components as shown in the official vue docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn. In their case however, the 'vue-style' component is created right there and not imported. In my case I already have existing root component along with some children that I would need to import into the html file (screenshot with project structure: https://imgur.com/a/m5JyINx). My issue is that it seems that imports of .vue files are not allowed, which means I would need to transpile my component to js. before importing them.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. You'll have to ditch CDN in favor of a common Vue setup with build tools - Vue CLI and more recently, Vite. The comments above describe this scenario.

Comment: I understand, sorry for coming off as a bit stubborn in my previous posts, I was really hoping that the CDN setup would work but I now realize that it is far too clumbersome and inefficient, I'll look into build tools like vue cli and vite and report back.

Comment: Hey, I got it to work using the build files generated via vue-cli. The reason I neglected that approach is because it didnt work at the very beginning, which was caused by the missing publicPath variable in the config file, which has now been fixed. The issue I'm having now is that im trying to create a web-component with some custom vue libraries. Unfortunately Im having some issues with formatting/css being broken when I use it, though that is a topic for another thread. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked for you in some way. WC may have their own quirks, it depends on your case if they are really necessary. They probably aren't, considering that you run the app in a specific environment where WC flexibility and isolation may not be necessary